# sharelatex image not shows up

Tags: graphics, packages, sharelatex

I'm using sharelatex with the Polimi Thesis project.
When I'm trying to include images, they not show up. The problem seems related to the package: `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`
But when I remove it for use only `graphicx`, the images start to showing up but the entire structure of the text is not conformed to the page size (text exceed the border page).
Thanks in advice for any further reply.

Packages in the main `.tex file`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }
\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\end{document}
```

When I try to load an image:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{<filename>.png}}
\caption{Terza generazione ICS: in rete}
\label{fig:figura3}
\end{figure}
```

I used fbox for view the box related to the image and it appeared but it is empty (no image inside)

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) what exactly are you using to compile this? If you are compiling with pdflatex that option is wrong

Comment: main file is not of big help. please make small but complete, self contained document beginning with `\documenntclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. include in it only necessary packages and not use `\include{<any file>}` since we haven't your files. only on this way we can (eventually) identified your problem and suggest solution(s). welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to use each compiler offered by the sharelatex engine but with the same results (no images) or in some cases with the structured mixed

Comment: Don't know if it'll make a difference but try removing `[dvipdfmx]`, so you have just `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already tried, the imges shows up but the entire structure of the text exceed the border of the pages

Comment: Remove all the manual settings of papersize and margins, and use the `geometry` package to adjust those things instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm new with Latex, are you able to suggest me how to implement the same structure of the page configured above with the geometry package?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by removing the `[dvipdfmx]` package option and all the manual papersize and margins, using instead the `geometry` package.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).